# Question about proof of corollary to splitting lemma.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Def. a)** A morphism $f : L \rightarrow M$ is called a section if there exists a morphism $h : M \rightarrow L$ such that $h \circ f = \text{id}_L$.

**Def. b)** A morphism $g : M \rightarrow N$ is called a retraction if there exists a morphism $h : N \rightarrow M$ such that $g \circ h = \text{id}_N$.

**Def. c)** We say that a short exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow L \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} N \rightarrow 0 $$
splits if $f$ is a section.

**Proposition.** Let $0 \rightarrow L \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} N \rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence. Then

1. $f$ is a section if and only if $g$ is a retraction.
2. If $f$ is a section, then $\text{im}\,f (=\text{ker}\,g)$ is a direct summand of $M$.

**Corollary.** If the sequence
$0 \rightarrow L \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} N \rightarrow 0$
is split exact, then
$M \cong L \oplus N$.

**Proof.** Since $f$ is injective, we have $L \cong f(L) \cong \text{ker}(g)$, and since $g$ is surjective, the first isomorphism theorem implies $N \cong M/\text{ker}(g)$. Now the result follows from the Proposition.

**Question:** I'm confused by the last sentence of the proof of the corollary. How exactly does the result follow from the proposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition tells you that $M\cong L\oplus P$ for some $P$, in such a way that $f\colon L\to M$ corresponds to $(-,0)\colon L\to L\oplus P$, so $P\cong (L\oplus P)/L\cong M/\mathrm{im}\,f\cong M/\mathrm{ker}\,g\cong N$.

Edit: In more detail, if $\mathrm{im}\,f$ is a direct summand of $M$, then there is a submodule $P$ of $M$ such that the map $\mathrm{im}\,f\oplus P\to M$ induced by the inclusions $\mathrm{im}\,f\hookrightarrow M$ and $P\hookrightarrow M$ is an isomorphism. The composition $L\xrightarrow{(f,0)}\mathrm{im}\,f\oplus P\xrightarrow{\cong} M$ therefore will equal $f\colon L\to M$, and the isomorphism $L\oplus P\to \mathrm{im}\,f\oplus P\to M$ yields, when precomposed with $L\xrightarrow{(-,0)}L\oplus P$, the map $f\colon L\to M$ again.

Now, the cokernel of the map $L\xrightarrow{(-,0)}L\oplus P$ is $P$. You may recognize this as the statement that the sequence $0\to L\to L\oplus P\to P\to 0$ is a short exact sequence. You can check $P\cong (L\oplus P)/L$ on elements by noting that on the right we are looking at pairs $(l,p)\in L\oplus P$ under the equivalence relation $(l,0)\sim (0,0)$ for any $l\in L$. Therefore, any element in the quotient can be uniquely represented in the form $(0,p)$ for some $p\in P$.

Comment: I'm a little confused:  I understand we get from part 1 of the proposition that "$M\cong L\oplus P$ for some $P$...", but you go on to write "...in such a way that $f\colon L\to M$ corresponds to $(-,0)\colon L\to L\oplus P$" and I'm not sure how you infer that from the proposition?

Also, how do you get "$P \cong (L \oplus P)/L$"?

Comment: I added some details. Let me know if this clears things up.